# Regex match images but not inside img tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a function which converts all external image links into img tags in a string.
It works well but also matches links inside `<img>` tag

for example:

```
$text = '<p>lorem ipsum http://example.jpg <img src="example.jpg"></p>';
echo make_clickable($text);

function make_clickable($text) {
    $replace = '<p class="update-image"><a href="$0" target="_blank"><img src="$0"></a></p>';
    $text = preg_replace('~https?://[^/\s]+/\S+\.(jpg|png|gif)~i', $replace, $text );
    return $text;
}
```

this test will match both, plain text and `src` too.
it there a way to exclude `img` tag?

Comment: You could take a look at negative lookaheads and negative lookbehinds :) http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is an excellent tool for both learning and trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use some non-well-known regex power:

```
<img[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|https?://[^/\s]+/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif)
```

Let's explain the pattern a bit:

```
<img                # match a literal <img
[^>]*               # match anything except > zero or more times
>                   # match a literal >
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # make it fail
|                   # or
https?              # match http or https
://                 # match a literal ://
[^/\s]+             # match anything except white-space and forward slash one or more times
/                   # match a literal /
\S+                 # match a non-white-space one or more times
\.                  # match a literal dot
(?:jpe?g|png|gif)   # match jpg, jpeg, png, gif
                    # Don't forget to set the i modifier :)
```

The idea is to match the `img` tag and skip it, meanwhile match all those URI's.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cH2qX2)</kbd>

Comment: Always a fan of (*SKIP)(*F) +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$replace = '<p class="update-image"><a href="$1" target="_blank"><img src="$1"></a></p>';
$text = preg_replace('~(https?://[^/\s]+/\S+\.(jpg|png|gif))(?:\s|$|\n)~i', $replace, $text );
```

**EDIT**: Your regex doesn't seem to match anything in my tests, but what I've added at the end is `(?:\s|$|\n)`.  I hope you get the point.

Comment: strange but now they have <br /> in the end

Comment: That's because it matches the whitespace/new line after the link, and you prolly have `nl2br` somewhere laying around. I remember to have dealed with this problem in the past but can't recall the solution unfortunately..

Comment: if the logic is to always match whitespace/newline then I can just delete last character no?

Comment: The solution is obvious, too bad we're not looking for obvious `:D`