# PHP text to HTML href link (ignore image link) with regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

I need regular expression that converts links in plain text to HTML links.
my code is:

```
preg_replace('/(((f|ht){1}tps:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
                   '<a href="\\1" target="_blank">\\1</a>', $text);
```

but this expression will make the image url to href as well.
so my question is how to avoid if the url is in img tag like.

The text:
`https://yahoo.com this is my image <img src="https://img.com/img.jpg">`

The result with my expression:`<a href="https://yahoo.com">https://yahoo.com</a> this is my image <img src="<a href="https://img.com/img.jpg">https://img.com/img.jpg</a>">`

i want this one `<a href="https://yahoo.com">https://yahoo.com</a> this is my image <img src="http://img.com/img.jpg">`

Comment: You should show the exact plain text you have then the expected converted output right after for each example, itll be much easier to help

Comment: And I tagged `php` for you, since you're using `preg_replace()` it may certainly matter with `regex`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305942/regex-match-images-but-not-inside-img-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using negative lookbehind operator `(?<!text)`, though probably not the most efficient way since the engine will back track a lot. Maybe you could do `strip_tags('img')` before `preg_replace`?

Another drawback of lookbehind is that it has to be fixed length. This means you cannot grab onto `img` since there may be additional attributes between it and the `src`. Anyhow, if you're really tempted to use it, your regex would look like this

```
preg_replace('/(?<!src=[\'"])(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
               '<a href="\\1" target="_blank">\\1</a>', $text);
```

Also, no need for second expression, as [Gavriel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34737373/5622021) points out, just add an `s?`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have it twice? The only difference I see is the s in the https, but that you could achieve like this:

```
preg_replace('/(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
               '<a href="\\1" target="_blank">\\1</a>', $text);
```

IMHO you got the result because the 1st line did what you wanted for and the second line "did it once again". If your input has the link and the img url in one line then you could maybe combine the 2 regexes to 1 long one that catches both. That way the 2nd each "half" of the regex will only replace it's "part" of the line